# Generic Types in NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm learning about CoreData and I have a rather basic question.

When I make an NSManagedObject subclass, the generated code in some places goes out of its way to make nicely typed functions for me, but in other cases leaves things annoyingly generic, and I'm confused why.

For example, I have a pair of managed classes with a parent/child, one to many (ordered) relationship.  ClassA is the parent which can hold many instances of ClassB.

In the managed code generated for ClassA, it gives the container for the ClassB items as:

```
@NSManaged public var items: NSOrderedSet?
```

This is generic, but then later in the code there are lots of conveniently typed functions such as this one:

```
@objc(insertObject:inItemsAtIndex:)
@NSManaged public func insertIntoItems(_ value: ClassB, at idx: Int)
```

Great... but a fundamental one is missing: A strongly-typed accessor to get the items collection.

I can easily cast things of course:

```
var myItem = myObjectOfClassA.items[0] as! ClassB
```

But I'm confused... Why did they go out of their way to make nicely typed functions in lots of cases, but leave one of the most fundamental things generic?

I'm assuming there is something basic I don't understand here.

Answer (score 0):

Because Swift and Foundation, that's why.

It's as generic as it's currently possible for this kind of relationship. It isn't more generic because

- `NSOrderedSet` is not generic, so you can't have `NSOrderedSet<ClassB>`, for example.
- Although Swift includes generic collections like `Array` and `Set`, there is no Swift-y generic `OrderedSet` collection.

There are also Swift-related gaps in the Core Data code generation. For example if this relationship wasn't ordered, the generated code would still use a non-generic `NSSet`. There's no good reason for that, but at least it can be cast to a `Set`.